# FBNativeAdTableViewCellProvider UITableView scroll performance

Tags: ios, facebook-ads-api, facebook-audience-network

I am using `FBNativeAdTableViewCellProvider` to manage `UITableViewCell` at runtime. The `FBNativeAdManager` is being used to provide ads to the `FBNativeAdTableViewCellProvider`.

There is a lot of jerk/lag visible when any Video ad is being shown in `UITableView` while scrolling.

There is neither a way I can use *reuse-identifier* to avoid multiple instances of the cell nor any way to stop auto playback of the ads.

I have tried using custom cell to draw view by using `FBMediaView` but this also results in lag and `autoplayEnabled` property doesn't seem to be working too.

Someone from Facebook seriously needs to have a look at it. Please let me know if anybody has successfully implemented the same.

Here is a chunk of code I am using:

```
self.fbNativeAdCellProvider= [[FBNativeAdTableViewCellProvider alloc] initWithManager:self.fbNativeAdsManager forType:FBNativeAdViewTypeGenericHeight300];
```

and in UITableViewDataSource method:

```
return [self.fbNativeAdCellProvider tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```